# WSS error when trying to check out PDF files

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a strange issue in WSS 3.0. It uses forms-based authentication and is under ISA. I can check out any file except PDF files. When I check out a PDF I get "Value does not fall within the expected range." I suspect this has something to do with ISA and where SSL is terminated. I have had problems before where links that should be https were showing up as http in the site.

For the present issue I have tried various AAM settings and nothing seems to make any difference at all in the operation of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the "value does not fall within the expected range" the other day in a forms service form that had an upload field.  The fix for me was to add the enctype= multipart/formdata to the application.master form tag.  Probably unrelated but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks but this had no apparent effect in my case.

Answer (score 0):

We have had this error when trying to save a file to a location that does not exist.

Check that it is PDF files that are failing, not that it is files from list x, where all PDF files are only in list x.

Comment: I can't get as far as specifying the location to save because it throws the error before I get to the save dialog. 
I have looked in the SharePoint javascript and while there are some lists of file extensions there, PDF is not in any of those lists. On this project I have not been able to find any other file type that causes it,  although on a different project it seems to happen when you check out any file.